how to align a content block left for desktop and center for mobile
I have a content block with an image to the left and content + cta to the right. I'm looking for a way to keep it left aligned for desktop view but centralize the image, header, text, cta when in mobile view, I've tried using conditional comments and specifying things like class=mobile only.
Is there a way to get this to render correctly for both desktop and mobile view?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You have to use css specific and target to mobile/devices based on conditional media tag like below
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.content-block {
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
}
